# Rmd - Knit renders σ as s in PDF

Tags: r, pdf, markdown, knitr

I am preparing a Rmd document for translation into a PDF. Here is how sample text looks like:

```
# Introduction
This document shows some plots of caliper data and its relation to the 2σ value.
```

In the generated PDF, the σ is rendered as a s. For mathematical equations, problems with rendering can be understood. But, this is about a simple Unicode character; just like English text. Interestingly, µ renders correctly. How do I ensure proper rendering?

Comment: Maybe a workaround is to use `$\sigma$` instead. Have you tried that?

Comment: No; for two reasons. First, as I mentioned before, this is about another Unicode character. Second, µ renders correctly. I will try that notation and report.

Comment: How do you convert the Rmd, what is the encoding of the file, what is the output of `session_info()`, can you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please?

Comment: The `$\sigma$` worked.

Comment: @user2706569 The MCVE is shown in the question. I am converting it from RStudio by clicking on the Knitr button. Note that, the problem does not happen with the µ character. So, it is not really about encoding but, something else (that I do not know).